# Number Formatting Functions Do Not Evaluate with ExportString

Tags: export, style

I need to export in a particular text file format and tried `NumberForm`, `PaddedForm`, `AccountingForm`, and `DecimalForm` to see which would work best.  To my surprise only `NumberForm` evaluates when exporting. The other functions export an WL expression with their head.

```
Function[{form},
   ExportString[
    form[#, {14, 2}, ExponentStep -> Infinity] & /@ {1 10^6, 2 10^6}, 
    "Table"]
   ] /@ {NumberForm, PaddedForm, AccountingForm, DecimalForm} // Map[Panel]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Mma 11.2 on Win 7 Ent 64bit

Comment: Add `ToString @ form`

Comment: @Kuba That did it. I still think it is odd that the others need this and not `NumberForm` when exporting as they all have function heads; `#[1 10^6, {14, 2}, ExponentStep -> Infinity] & /@ {NumberForm, PaddedForm, AccountingForm, DecimalForm} // Map[Head]`. Strange?

Comment: I'm not sure, my guess is that Export does context-sensitive formatting. And formatting for those wrappers is not defined. (here Table is that context). Which is fine in general but it is strange for number forms. p.s. it is not about evaluation but about formatting (kernel typesetting).