# DecimalForm export problem

Tags: export, formatting

When I'm trying to export data formatted using DecimalForm I have "DecimalForm[0.002, 4], DecimalForm[0.0004567, 4]" in the exported file for the following example

```
ll = {0.002, 0.0004567}
Table[DecimalForm[ll[[i]], 4], {i, 1, ll // Length}]
Export["/dir/ll_d.csv", %]
Table[NumberForm[ll[[i]], 4], {i, 1, ll // Length}]
Export["/dir/ll_n.csv", %]
```

still in notebook all looks fine. I have no any issue for NumberForm for example the output file is correct. What is the point? I cannot understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158694/number-formatting-functions-do-not-evaluate-with-exportstring).

Comment: Agree this is a duplicate. But to address the "I cannot understand" comment... All of the `*Form` functions are just wrappers that tell the front end how to display an expression. If you do`FullForm[DecimalForm[0.0004567, 2]]` you'll see `DecimalForm[0.0004567, 2]`. By the way, FullForm is itself one of these special functions, and you need to be careful with it too.

Comment: Once you've wrapped something like this, it's a different "type", and functions operate differently on it, if at all.  If you evaluate `x = 0.0004567; x + x`, you'll get `0.0009134`. If you evaluate `xdf = DecimalForm[0.0004567, 2]; xdf + xdf`, you'll get `2 0.00046` (which is really `Times[2, DecimalForm[0.0004567, 2]]`).

Comment: In fact I was just confused by different behaviour of DecimalForm and NumberForm. Why NumberForm is evaluated before export, but not DecimalForm?